# How to run several different functions syncronized

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I have 4 functions running on nodejs

```
function func1(vl){
 // do something
}

function func2(vl){
 // do something
}

function func3(vl){
 // do something
}

function func4(vl){
 // do something
}

func1('Js');
func2('Css');
func3('Img');
func4('Fonts');
```

I want to run the functions sync (func1 run first, func2 after etc....)

Not func4 run before func1 (its asunc and i want it sync)

Answer (score 0):

[**How to use Async**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#seriestasks-callback)

See `async.series()`  or  `async.waterfall()`.
that will work for you.I have given some answer here.

[**see my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953629/sailsjs-nested-callback-in-async-waterfall-function-not-returning-correct-value/35954621#35954621)